# Google Maps Store Locator PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I'm attempting to follow this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

Unfortunately, I keep getting blank values in my XML output:

```
<Competitors>
    <Competitors Name="" Address="" lat="" lng="" Distance="0"/>
    <Competitors Name="" Address="" lat="" lng="" Distance="0"/>
    <Competitors Name="" Address="" lat="" lng="" Distance="0"/>
    <Competitors Name="" Address="" lat="" lng="" Distance="0"/>
    <Competitors Name="" Address="" lat="" lng="" Distance="0"/>
    <Competitors Name="" Address="" lat="" lng="" Distance="0"/>
    <Competitors Name="" Address="" lat="" lng="" Distance="0"/>
    <Competitors Name="" Address="" lat="" lng="" Distance="0"/>
    <Competitors Name="" Address="" lat="" lng="" Distance="0"/>
    <Competitors Name="" Address="" lat="" lng="" Distance="0"/>
</Competitors>
```

I've set up a table in my database similar to what is shown in the tutorial:

[image: Table Screenshot]

and here is my code for generating XML, per the tutorial:

```
<?php  
$username="#######";
$password="#######";
$database="#######";

// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("Competitors");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ("host", $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Search the rows in the Competitors table
$query = sprintf("SELECT 'Address', 'Name', 'Lat', 'Lng', 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( 'Lat' ) ) * cos( radians( 'lng' ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( 'Lat' ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM Competitors 
HAVING distance < '%s' 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("Competitors");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("Name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("Address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("Distance", $row['distance']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

I'm not sure where I made a mistake - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you have a capitalization problem ('lat' vs 'Lat', etc) in your query.

Comment: mysql is deprecated as of 5.5 and you can use mysqli_* since 5.3 I would advise moving to that, https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation

Comment: Have you appended something like this to your url like the docs says  ?lat=37&lng=-122&radius=25

Comment: Yeah, when I append with lat, lng and radius, I get the above XML output

Comment: All about capitalization: lat => Lat, lng => Lng, address => Address, name => Name and distance => Distance in `$row`

Comment: remove the @. it is never good to suppress error messages, especially during debugging.

Comment: The capitalization fixed it - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace this

```
// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ('host', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}
```

with

```
// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}
```

Just tried it and i get xml

Also the code example just used `localhost` instead of `"localhost"` so php thinks it's a constant